# how to use a sublass of a template class to deduce the template parameters of a template function in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

This could be very silly...

If I have such a template class A,

```
template <class T1, class T2>
struct A
{
    T1 a;
    T2 b;
};
```

and a function works on it,

```
template <class T1, class T2>
void foo(A<T1, T2> *p)
{
}
```

now I subclass A,

```
struct B : A<int, int>
{
};

B b[100];
```

I can not deduce template parameter...

```
foo(b);
```

and I have to write like this,

```
foo((B *)b);
```

or like this,

```
foo<int, int>(b);
```

and now something more,
I wish foo can accept something T other than A and treat them as A

```
template <class T>
struct A<T, void>
{
    T a;
};

template <class T>
void foo(T *p)
{
    foo((A<T, void> *)p);
}
```

now unless I write like this, the later foo is called...

```
foo<int, int>(b);
```

1. How can I make deducing template parameters from array of subclass easier?
2. How can I make subclass have higher priority than other class when locating overloaded function?

---

This seems will do

```
template <class T>
struct is_A_derived
{
    typedef char (&yes)[1];
    typedef char (&no)[2];

    template <class T1, class T2>
    static yes test(A<T1, T2> *);
    static no test(...);

    template <class T1, class T2>
    static A<T1, T2> get_type(A<T1, T2> *);
    static A<T, void> get_type(...);

    template <class T1, class T2>
    static A<T1, T2> base_type(A<T1, T2> *);
    static int base_type(...); // guess or maybe hope this "int" is never used

    static const bool value = sizeof(test((T *)0)) == sizeof(yes);
    static const bool identical = value && sizeof(base_type((T *)0)) == sizeof(T);

    typedef typename std::conditional<identical, decltype(get_type((T *)0)), A<T, void>>::type type;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, there is actually a danger of decaying an array of B to an A* pointer, in case you happen do to pointer arithmetic on the A* pointer.

It surprises me that it doesn't resolve but could be a nice safety feature, just in case you are planning to perform a function over an array of A, which won't work with an array of B.

You could do `foo( &b[0] )` rather than casting or explicit templating.

In the latter case you are now complicating things with a function foo on your T* if it has the same name as the function on the A template.

Once you add the second foo, the call on B will indeed choose the second foo because it now becomes a perfect match. The subclass can be given a higher priority with clever SFINAE techniques to see if it is an A or not. Generally though I would avoid using this unless you really have to.

Comment: SFINAE seems solved the major part of the problem. Thanks. But still some work to do like preventing enlarged subclass from being used.

Answer (score 1):

Just be advised that this code *will* fail. You cannot use C style arrays polymorphically (regardless of templates).

That is, you cannot treat an array-of-`B` as an array-of-`A`.

What do you think will happen if you write `p[1]`? Well, the following happens internally:

```
*(p + 1)
```

Pointer arithmetic. Now, the `+ 1` is further translated by the compiler into an increment by `sizeof A` bytes. But your data structure isn’t `sizeof A` large, it’s `sizeof B`! So `p[1]` will point at the wrong location in memory.

So the compiler is (entirely accidentally!) doing the right thing by forbidding this call.

Comment: Well, it will not fail. B and A<int, int> are of the same size. Though it is not restricted here, A is not planned to be derived with additional member variables (nor hidden pointers to some tables). But this seems really a problem.